# Is the figure the circumference of a unit circle?

Tags: geometry, circles, combinatorial-geometry

A friend of mine taught me the following question. I've never heard such a strange and interesting question!

**Qustion**: Supposing that a figure $S$, which is constituted by points, satisfies the following four conditions, can we say that $S$ is the circumference of a unit circle?

*1.* $S$ crosses at **two** points every line which passes through the origin.

*2.* $S$ crosses at **one** point every tangent of the unit circle whose center is the origin.

*3.* $S$ crosses at **two** points every line $L_x$ which  satisfies the following two:
(i) $L_x$ is parallel to $x$-axis. (2) The distance $d_x$ between $L_x$ and $x$-axis satisfies $d_x\lt1$.

*4.* $S$ crosses at **two** points every line $L_y$ which  satisfies the following two:
(i) $L_y$ is parallel to $y$-axis. (2) The distance $d_y$ between $L_y$ and $y$-axis satisfies $d_y\lt1$.

I've tried to solve this, but I'm facing difficulty. He said the answer is **NO** without his memory of the very figure. Can we find a special counterexample?

*Edit* : I'm sorry. The **Question 2** is not an appropriate question, so I deleted it.

Comment: Surely answer to Q1 is YES. A unit circle with center at origin seems to satisfy all the conditions.

Comment: @Mufasa -- What you say is true (maybe), but the question asks whether this circle is the **only** figure with the given properties.

Comment: I don't get question 2. How can the circumference of a circle cross a line at four points?

Comment: @bubba -- Doesn't Q1 point 2 imply that the curve cannot live outside or inside the unit circle - it MUST live on the unit circle itself?

Comment: @Mufasa No. I managed to construct a figure has property 2 and looked nothing like a circle.

Comment: @fluorine -- Can you upload a drawing of this curve please?

Comment: Note also, it is stated that the figure consists of points. Therefore it doesn't have to be a continuous curve.

Comment: @Mufasa https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51691758/testlatex2.pdf satisfies property 2, 3 and 4, but not 1. Each of the vertical lines has length infinitesimally smaller than $\sqrt{2} - 1$, while each of the horizontal lines has length exactly $\sqrt{2} - 1$. The black and white circles are not part of the figure.

Comment: @fluorine -- I stand corrected! I never thought of it like that - thanks for posting the figure. I guess the white circles represent EXCLUDED points (i.e. EXCLUDE the end point of the line of length $\sqrt{2}−1$) and the black one are INCLUDED points (i.e. INCLUDE the end point of the line of length $\sqrt{2}−1$).

Comment: @fluorine -- I believe your figure does not satisfy conditions 3 and 4. I think the x- and y- axes themselves are also included here and these lines would cross your figure at an infinite number of points.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Thank you for pointing it out. I deleted the question 2.

Comment: @Mufasa: I suppose it depends on whether "parallel to the $x$ (or $y$) axis" allows them to coincide with the axis. If not, then fluorine's figure satisfies 3 and 4.

Comment: @CameronBuie -- e.g. statement 3 says "The distance $d_x$ between $L_x$ and x-axis satisfies $d_x<1$". This includes $d_x=0$ which would put $L_x$ on the x-axis itself.

Comment: @Mufasa: True, but if "parallel" indicates distinct as part of the definition, then implicitly we have $d_x>0$. This is further supported by the fact that the $x$- and $y$-axis are already taken care of in condition 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've just got the following figure.

[image]

**The answer for Question** is No.

$S$ has eight line segments $AB, CD, EF, GH, MN, OP, QR, ST$ and four points $I, J, K, L$ without twelve points $A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, M, P, R, T$ where 
$$A(0,1), B(-\frac12, \frac12), C(-1,0), D(-\frac12, -\frac12), E(0,-1), F(\frac12, -\frac12), G(1,0), H(\frac12, \frac12), I(0,\frac12), J(-\frac12, 0), K(0,-\frac12), L(\frac12,0), M(0,\sqrt{10}), N(\frac{\sqrt{10}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{10}}{2}), O(-\frac{\sqrt{10}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{10}}{2}), P(-\sqrt{10},0), Q(-\frac{\sqrt{10}}{2},-\frac{\sqrt{10}}{2}), R(0,-\sqrt{10}), S(\frac{\sqrt{10}}{2},-\frac{\sqrt{10}}{2}), T(\sqrt{10},0).$$

I think this figure is one of the counterexamples.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: This figure is not quite correct as a counterexample.

---

I managed to construct this counterexample. It is very, *very* "hackish" and contrived. It is probably not what your friend had in mind. But it *is* a counterexample!

Anything in $\color{blue}{\text{blue}}$ is not part of the actual figure.

[image]

1. Define (only this is in polar coordinates) $R(\varphi):=(\sqrt{2}, \varphi)$. Then the arc in first quadrant is defined as the set of points $\{R(\varphi):0 < \varphi < \pi/2\}$. Whereas the arc in third quadrant is defined as the set of points $\{R(\varphi):\pi < \varphi < 3\pi/2\}$.
2. $A = (0, A_y)$ such that $A_y < 1$ is infinitesimally close to $1$.
3. $B = (B_x,0)$ such that $B_x > -1$ is infinitesimally close to $-1$.
4. $C = (C_x, 0)$ such that $C_x < 1$ is infinitesimally close to $1$.
5. $D = (0, D_x)$ such that $D_x > -1$ is infinitesimally close to $-1$.
6. $P_1 = (-\sqrt{2}/2, \sqrt{2}/2)$.
7. $P_2 = (\sqrt{2}/2, -\sqrt{2}/2)$.

Please critique this figure.

Some comments:

1. You might be worried that the lines $y = 0$ and $x = 0$ would violate property 1, 3 and 4. They do not, because the arcs do not actually touch the axes.
2. Would the tangent lines $y = x \pm \sqrt{2}$ violate property 2? No, because, again, the arcs do not touch the axes and those tangent lines touch one and only one of the points $P_1$ and $P_2$.
3. Each of the tangent lines $y = \pm 1$ crosses only at one point. They pass through neither point $A$ nor $D$.

Comment: Saying two real numbers are "infinitesimally close" is nonsensical. Just put unfilled circles at the end of the segments to indicate exclusion of those points, and all is well. That aside, this figure isn't quite what is needed. The tangent lines at $x=y=\pm\frac{\sqrt2}2$ do not intersect your figure at all, nor do the $x$- and $y$-axes.

Comment: @CameronBuie Thanks for your criticisms. I defined (for example) $A$ in that "nonsensical" way because I needed $A_x = 0$ exactly (otherwise the line $x = 0$ wouldn't intersect anything), while $A_y$ to be made as close to $1$ as possible, but not reaching it. Anyway should I delete this answer, or make it clear that this is a failed attempt?

Comment: Ah! I see what you were attempting to do with the "infinitesimal" bit, but that introduces the problem that if $A_y<1,$ then (for example) the horizontal line $y=\frac{A_y+1}2$ intersects the figure in only one point. I wouldn't delete it, yet. Just make a note that it doesn't quite work as it is. It's possible that it can be salvaged.